# Apply function to 2nd column in pandas dataframe groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a pandas dataframe, a function can be used to group its index. I'm looking to define a function that instead is applied to a column.

I'm looking to group by two columns, except I need the second column to be grouped by an arbitrary function, `foo`:

```
group_sum = df.groupby(['name', foo])['tickets'].sum()
```

How would `foo` be defined to group the second column into two groups, demarcated by whether values are `> 0`, for example? Or, is an entirely different approach or syntax used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Groupby can accept any combination of both labels and series/arrays (as long as the array has the same length as your dataframe), so you can map the function to your column and pass it into the groupby, like

```
df.groupby(['name', df[1].map(foo)])
```

Alternatively you might want to add the condition as a new column to your dataframe before your perform the groupby, this will have the advantage of giving it a name in the index:

```
df['>0'] = df[1] > 0
group_sum = df.groupby(['name', '>0'])['tickets'].sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work:

```
x.groupby(['name', x['value']>0])['tickets'].sum()
```

Like mentioned above the `groupby` can accept labels and series. This should give you the answer you are looking for. Here is an example:

```
data = np.array([[1, -1, 20], [1, 1, 50], [1, 1, 50], [2, 0, 100]])
x = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'value', 'value2'])
x.groupby(['name', x['value']>0])['value2'].sum()

name  value
1     False     20
      True     100
2     False    100
Name: value2, dtype: int64
```